# Trying to resolve an ASP Classic Script revolving around two buttons. It contains two buttons when only needing one

Tags: html, asp.net, asp-classic

here is the ASP Script and the html elements inside of the body tags. For some reason it is giving me TWO buttons instead of one. My Goal is just trying to remove one of the buttons so it can lead me into the View cart feature page. Thank you for the help!

```
<%
catid = Request.QueryString("id")
sub productInfo(connObj,category)
sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM qryProdsCategory WHERE ccategory = '" & Cint(category) & "'"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset")
rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
if not rs.EOF then
    if Session("sort")="0" then
        rs.sort = "cname ASC"
    end if

Response.Write "<form action="&q&Application("secureurl")&"/cart/view-cart.asp"&q&"       method="&q&"POST"&q&" name=form"&i&">"

        while not rs.EOF

            If rs("stock")="1" then

                Response.Write "<a href=""product.asp?id=" & rs("catalogID") & ""

                Response.Write "" & rs("catalogID") & "" & rs("manModNum") & "</font></td><td width=""18%"" rowspan=""2"">"
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fproductid"&q&" value="&q &  rs("catalogID")& q&">" 
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fquantity"&q&" value=1>" 
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fcat"&q&" value=" & rs("ccategory") & ">"

            End If

        rs.MoveNext
        wend

        If rs.RecordCount > 0 then
             Response.Write "<button class=""btn"" TYPE=""btn"" style=""background-color: #cb0000;color: #fff;"">ADD TO CART</button> </form>" 
        End If
 Response.Write "</form>" 
else
    Response.Write "&nbsp;<P><Center><font size=""2""><h3>Sorry, but products information for the category you have chosen is not available at this moment. Please check back soon!</H3></font></center>"
    catname = "Error"
end if
end sub
%>
```

Here is the code inside the body tags

```
<div class="span3">
<img src="img/team/profile1.jpg">
<div class="productSelection">
<div class="ProductTitle">
<strong style="font-size:16px;">TITLE</strong>
</div>
<h6>TITLE</h6>
<h6>TITLE</h6>


<%
call openConn()
call productInfo(dbc,catid)
%>
```

This is the Edited part of the View Cart Section of the ASP Code

```
<%
catid = Request.QueryString("id")
sub productInfo(connObj,category)
sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM qryProdsCategory WHERE ccategory = '" & Cint(category) & "'"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset")
rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
if not rs.EOF then
    if Session("sort")="0" then
        rs.sort = "cname ASC"
    end if

Response.Write "<form action="&q&Application("secureurl")&"/cart/view-cart.asp"&q&"      method="&q&"POST"&q&" name=form"&i&">"

        while not rs.EOF

            If rs("stock")="1" then

                Response.Write "<a href=""product.asp?id=" & rs("catalogID") & ""

                Response.Write "" & rs("catalogID") & "" & rs("manModNum") & "</font></td><td width=""18%"" rowspan=""2"">"
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fproductid"&q&" value="&q &   rs("catalogID")& q&">" 
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fquantity"&q&" value=1>" 
                Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fcat"&q&" value=" &  rs("ccategory") & ">"

            End If

        rs.MoveNext
        wend
   %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting two buttons because you are creating them within the `While` loop. The condition within the while loop may be satisfied couple of times (I mean your code goes to the `Else` part where you create the button all the time). Move the button creation logic out of the while loop. And, your If...Else code to create the button doesn't make sense. I.e. whatever the condition it creates a button. According to my understanding you are trying to show the Add to Cart button only if there are records. If that's true I suggest something like this.

```
<%
catid = Request.QueryString("id")
sub productInfo(connObj,category)
    sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM qryProdsCategory WHERE ccategory = '" & Cint(category) & "'"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset")
    rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    if not rs.EOF then
        if Session("sort")="0" then
            rs.sort = "cname ASC"
        end if

Response.Write "<form action="&q&Application("secureurl")&"/cart/view-cart.asp"&q&"      method="&q&"POST"&q&" name=form"&i&">"

            while not rs.EOF

                If rs("stock")="1" then

                    Response.Write "<a href=""product.asp?id=" & rs("catalogID") & ""

                    Response.Write "" & rs("catalogID") & "" & rs("manModNum") & "</font></td><td width=""18%"" rowspan=""2"">"
                    Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fproductid"&q&" value="&q &  rs("catalogID")& q&">" 
                    Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fquantity"&q&" value=1>" 
                    Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fcat"&q&" value=" & rs("ccategory") & ">"

                End If

            rs.MoveNext
            wend

            If rs.RecordCount > 0 then
                Response.Write "<button class=""btn"">ADD TO CART</button>" 
            End If
 Response.Write "</form>" 
    else
        Response.Write "&nbsp;<P><Center><font size=""2""><h3>Sorry, but products information for the category you have chosen is not available at this moment. Please check back soon!</H3></font></center>"
        catname = "Error"
    end if
end sub
%>
```

Hope this helped! Vote and accept the answer if it did. All the best :-)

Comment: Not only that, the `<form>` tag is also opened in the loop, this is probably not what is desired.

Comment: Good morning @Sam! Thank you very much for your help! It does remove the secondary button, but it is now giving me an error in actually going through to the "View Cart" section. I am very new to ASP and I am trying to get an understanding of all of this!Thanks Again!

Comment: Update your question with the error message so that we could have a look. And, accept this answer since it resolved your issue. That's how we get rewarded you know :)

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you and I will update it. I tried voting up yesterday, but it is telling me I need 15 reputation to actually be able to vote up. Sucks. I cant even post an image yet until I have 10 reputations. Sorry I am very new to this!

Comment: I just updated my question. Is there any other way to accept an answer or is it by just voting up? @sam

Comment: Hi Sam, Im glad that was it LOL I updated the script on my main question, but the view cart feature has an error when clicked on the button. Not sure what can be the problem with it. Do you have an Idea?

Comment: @Sam  error message that pops up when clicked is "GET cart/images/topbgfade.jpg 404 (Not Found) "

Comment: It seems like you are not giving the correct path for the image topbgfade.jpg. Update your question with view-cart.asp code

Comment: @Sam I just put the section of where the View cart is given. Hopefully that helps a bit. Thank you for all of your help !